# Upgrading JSF 1.2 to 2.x NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, spring-security, myfaces

I've scoured the Internet and SO but I can't seem to find an answer.  The issue is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143537/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-com-sun-faces-application-view-faceletviewhand) (with no answer) I've tried many suggestions including [this suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22279917/537566) and [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040214/537566).

So I inherited an old project that needs to run on a newer version of Tomcat.  The project uses **Apache's MyFaces (Trinidad)**. One task is to get JSF from 1.2 to 2.x. So I follow a few migration suggestions for both MyFaces and JSF but I'm stuck on the following error, described below.  I suspect `org.acegisecurity` because of error below and the fact that `index.xhtml` file is currently empty.  The login pages works fine but the secured index page throws this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:350)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:226)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
    org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:826)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.createView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:68)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.createView(MultiViewHandler.java:169)
    com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.createView(FaceletViewHandler.java:799)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.createView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:173)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.createView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:108)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:112)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:243)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:350)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:226)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
    org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
```

**Config Snippets**

*faces-config.xml*

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
```

*web.xml*

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:acegi-security-context.xml
            --- >8 [snip] 8< ---
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

*parent pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
    <artifactId>acegi-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad</groupId>
    <artifactId>trinidad-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad</groupId>
    <artifactId>trinidad-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

(Spring framework version 2.0.8 - let's get JSF working first)
Maybe I've stared myself blind and the answer is obvious to a new set of eyes.

Comment: Start by removing the explicit facelets dependency from your project. Facelets is included in JSF 2.x by default

Comment: @Gimby: I upvoted your comment but on checking OP want to use MyFaces **TRINIDAD**... A component set, not the MyFaces API so your comment is not valid

Comment: See the 'duplicate'. Next time start by creating a [mcve]. To see if it is e.g. Trinidad related, remove all that. Make a pages (or empty application) that has no spring-security configured. Narrow things down

Comment: @Kuketjie I get the following when accessing index.xhtml: `ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler` (And it is not coming from the project code.

Comment: Then put that error in google and see what it comes up with